# Is there a facility in OUTLOOK 2003 that will find and merge duplicate contacts?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, internet-explorer

Is there a facility in OUTLOOK 2003 that will find and merge duplicate contacts?

OS is Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround: How about exporting them, load them in gmail, let gmail do the duplicate searching and merging, and export them back into outlook?

Here's what seems to be a [commercial solution.](http://www.duplicatekiller.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I was just searching for the same thing and there doesn't appear to be an easy method of ***merging*** existing contacts.

These are the third-party apps I found:

- 1-Click Duplicate Delete (Trial Version, limited to 60 merges)

   http://www.easy2sync.com/en/produkte/1-Click-Duplicate-Delete-Outlook.php
- Duplicate Killer Merger (Trial Version, limited to 10 merges)

   http://duplicatekiller.4team.biz/ (linked in above post)
- Contacts Scrubber for Outlook (Trial Version, scans 100 items max)

   http://www.teamscope.com/otherpro/utilities.asp#scrubber

Hope the links help someone else out there.